# Using Azure PowerShell or AZ commands I want to check if a Azure DevOps Release Pipeline is executed or not? Is there any script available for it?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I want to validate if a Release Pipeline is executed or not using PowerShell without logging into the Azure DevOps project. How to test this? Also is it possible to get the output of the Release like if its succeeded or failed using PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > I want to validate if a Release Pipeline is executed or not using PowerShell without logging into the Azure DevOps project.

If you want to validate if a Release Pipeline is executed or not using PowerShell, below scripts can implement this.

1. [Create a PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#create-a-pat) with full scopes, and then use this Rest API: [Definitions - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to list all release pipelines. See below scripts.

```
    $url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=6.0"
     
    $connectionToken="PAT Here" #input your PAT
     
    $base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
     
    $pipelines = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get
     
    Write-Host "Pipeline = $($pipelines | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)" #list all release pieplines
```

2. You could find your target **release pipeline’s definition Id** from the above response. And then use this Rest API: [Releases – List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get all releases for this release pipeline. See below scripts.

```
    $new_url = https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases?definitionId={definitionId}&api-version=6.0
     
    $releases = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $new_url -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get
     
    Write-Host "releases = $($releases | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
```

3. If there are no releases in the response, then the release pipeline is not executed.

Comment: Thanks Edward. First snippet I was able to run successfully. For second snippet, Im getting error   "api-version=6.0 not recognized" How to provide the release number in below line of code for this part of code "definitionId= {definitionId}&api-version=6.0"                                                                                                     
 $new_url = https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases?definitionId= {definitionId}&api-version=6.0

Comment: The 1st snippet will return array of release pipeline's definitions, you could review it to find your target release pipeline’s definition Id, and then use this id as the value of parameter definitionId, and then run the 2nd snippet to get its releases list.

Comment: My release pipeline and code is inside a feature branch and I'm not able to see it in the REST API response, When I put the same number of the Feature Branch Release pipeline, it shows some other pipeline information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You firstly need to know the id of targeting release pipeline, and then directly using the 2nd snippet to get its releases list. Please using postman to check firstly and then make sure that your script is correct.

Comment: I'm able to execute the code in the steps 1. Getting list of pipelines 2. Get the pipeline id and retrieve the Release information and Release ID 3. Run the third script for Release id and get the response. These steps worked fine for me. I'm just now trying to extract the execution status out of all the json response.

Comment: If needed, [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#releasestatus) lists all release status, and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#taskstatus) lists all task status.

Answer (score 0):

You can use az commands:

1. Log in to your org with pat ([Sign in with a Personal Access Token (PAT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/log-in-via-pat?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows)):

   ```
   az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/org_name
   ```
2. Find id of your release definition (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/pipelines/release/definition?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_azure_devops_az_pipelines_release_definition_list)

   ```
   az pipelines release definition list --org https://dev.azure.com/org_name -p ProjectName --output table


   ID    Name                      CreatedBy          Created On
   ----  ------------------------  -----------------  --------------------------------
   2     New release pipeline (3)  UserName           2019-09-26T15:42:59.613000+00:00
   3     New release pipeline      UserName           2019-10-08T07:48:21.457000+00:00
   4     New release pipeline (1)  UserName           2019-11-19T19:04:40.523000+00:00
   5     New release pipeline (2)  UserName           2020-07-23T14:13:08.953000+00:00
   ```
3. Show all releases in your definition (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/pipelines/release?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_azure_devops_az_pipelines_release_list):

   ```
   az pipelines release list --definition-id 5 --org https://dev.azure.com/org_name -p ProjectName  --output table

   ID    Name       Definition Name           Created By   Created On                  Status    Description
   ----  ---------  ------------------------  -----------  --------------------------  --------  -------------
   177   Release-6  New release pipeline (2)  UserName     2020-12-22 19:28:06.610000  active    Triggered by 
   176   Release-5  New release pipeline (2)  UserName     2020-12-21 18:29:51.930000  active    Triggered by 
   175   Release-4  New release pipeline (2)  UserName     2020-12-18 12:52:04.610000  active    Triggered by 
   174   Release-3  New release pipeline (2)  UserName     2020-11-11 02:02:32.653000  active    Triggered by
   ```
4. Show one release (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/pipelines/release?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_azure_devops_az_pipelines_release_show)

   ```
   az pipelines release show --id 177 --org https://dev.azure.com/org_name -p ProjectName --output table

   ID    Name       Definition Name           Created By         Created On                  Status    Description
   ----  ---------  ------------------------  -----------------  --------------------------  --------  -------------
   177   Release-6  New release pipeline (2)  UserName           2020-12-22 19:28:06.610000  active    Triggered by
   ```

Additionally, you can play with `--output` parameter to get the result in the json format, then you'll get more detailed information.

Comment: Thank you Shamrai. That's Wonderful. Good to know this is available. I will play around it and will update the thread. Just one question how to get/generate the PAT for ADO?

Comment: You can find the instructions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#create-a-pat

Comment: I was successfully able to create the PAT using the link that you share But I'm getting error for az login that "Login failed to store PAT using Keyring.." I have logged out from all the sessions but not sure why this error is coming up for the az login.

Comment: @YogeshKulkarni, try to use AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT variable: https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension/blob/master/doc/samples.md#log-in-via-azure-devops-personal-access-token-pat